# Parse delimited string using awk and fetch the matched string

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a delimited string variable as mentioned below. I would like to grep a matched string. I found some possible solutions on the Internet, but sadly they did not give me the result I was expecting. Can you suggest or correct me.

```
Input: 123,src_12,234,456
       1,23,34,src_23,4,56,7
       src_14,12
       12,3,5,src_5
Output: src_12
        src_23
        src_14
        src_5
```

Logic: I need to fetch the string which has 'src_'. It's not always the second item in the list. The position may change. Variable length, delimited.

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po 'src_.*?\b' file`?

Comment: Thanks Cyrus for editing the text and comments. i dont have file. input is an variable.

Comment: `grep -Po '\bsrc_.*?\b' <<< "$variable"`?

Comment: What part of this question involves `bash` shell and needs the tag?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple `awk` solution:

```
awk 'match($0,/src_[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

or

```
awk '{sub(/.*src/,"src");sub(/\,.*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: When no match scenarios, it gives first string. How to avoid it

Comment: @srinath, please try to run first command only which should give output when a match is found only.

Comment: first statement fails when i have src_abc (non numeric) one.

Comment: @srinath, try `src_[0-9a-zA-Z]+` on place of `src_[0-9]+/` once and let know?

Comment: it worked partial. for src_12_abc i am getting src_12 only. i need data till next delimiter.

Comment: @srinath, change `/src_[0-9]+/` to `/src_[^ ][0-9a-zA-Z]+/` once?

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS="," read -a array; do
  for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ $element =~ ^src_ ]] && echo "$element"
  done
done <<< "$variable"
```

Output:

```
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tr

```
$ cat srinath.txt2
123,src_12,234,456
1,23,34,src_23,4,56,7
src_14,12
12,3,5,src_5
src_6,src_7,16,18

$ A=$(cat srinath.txt2)

$ tr ',' '\n' <<< "$A" | grep ^src
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
src_6
src_7
```

Comment: You can avoid the `cat`, but this will also pick up stuff like `vsrc_blabla`

Comment: I wanted to post about the same answer, only using `grep "^src_"` avoiding `vsrc_blabla`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat srinath.txt
123,src_12,234,456
1,23,34,src_23,4,56,7
src_14,12
12,3,5,src_5

$ perl -nle ' /(src_\d+)/ and print $1 ' srinath.txt
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
```

If you have more than one src_ in the same line, then use below

```
$ cat srinath.txt2
123,src_12,234,456
1,23,34,src_23,4,56,7
src_14,12
12,3,5,src_5
src_6,src_7,16,18

$ perl -nle ' while( /(src_\d+)/g ) { print $1 } ' srinath.txt2
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
src_6
src_7
```

If it is in a variable, then

```
$ A=$(cat srinath.txt2)

$ perl -nle ' while( /(src_\d+)/g ) { print $1 } '  <<< "$A"
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
src_6
src_7
```

or

```
$ export A="123,src_12,234,456,1,23,34,src_23,4,56,7,src_14,12,12,3,5,src_5,src_6,src_7,16,18"

$ perl -nle ' while( /(src_\d+)/g ) { print $1 } '  <<< "$A"
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
src_6
src_7

$ perl -le ' $_=$ENV{A}; while( /(src_\d+)/g ) { print $1 } '
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
src_6
src_7
```

Comment: yes.. you can call perl in middle of the bash program

Comment: Thank you for quick answer @stack0114106. I dont want to increase dependency by using perl. let me figure it out with bash. if nothing is working, i will use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!s/src_[^,]*/\n&\n/g;/^src_/P;D' file
```

Surround all candidate strings by newlines and then using the sed commands `P` and `D` whittle down each line printing only the candidates with the prefix `src_`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple grep returning only (`-o`) the matched words (`-w`)

```
$ grep -wo 'src_[^,]*' file
src_12
src_23
src_14
src_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `^src_xxx,`, `,src_xxx,` and `,src_xxx$`, and only print the match without the `,`.

```
sed -rn 's/.*(,|^)(src_[^,]*)(,|$).*/\2/p'
```